# Is this sufficient to show the two spaces are not isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing, vector-space-isomorphism

Yesterday I was studying about isomorphisms between vecto spaces, and basically the fundamental note I highlighted stated that "two vector spaces whose dimensions are different cannot be isomorphic, ever."

One of the canonical examples was like $\mathbb{R}^4 \not\cong \mathbb{R}^3$. Now the notes did not prove this, relying just on the above statement.

But then I thoguht to prove it, by using the definition of isomorphism that is, a linear map $1:1$ and onto. So I thought about this example: suppose there exist a map $h$ such that $h:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by the following action

$$\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a+b \\ c \\ d \end{pmatrix}$$

So then I observed that this map cannot be injective ($1:1$) since it would mean that given two vectors $v_1, v_2$

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ b_1 \\ c_1 \\ d_1 \end{pmatrix} \qquad v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} a_2 \\ b_2 \\ c_2 \\ d_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

then $h(v_1) = h(v_2)$ means

$$\begin{pmatrix} a_1+b_1 \\ c_1 \\ d_1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_2+b_2 \\ c_2 \\ d_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

And as far $c_1 = c_2$, $d_1 = d_2$, we are left with infinite possibilities about $a_1 + b_1 = a_2 + c_2$

Since it is not injective, it cannot be an isomorphism.

- Question(s): is this all right? Or did I just wrote a load of malarkey? :)
- How could I prove that this map is not onto? I tried but I cannot find anything good. Or maybe it is onto...
- If my reasoning is bugged, please can you fix it where necessary? Thank you so much!

Comment: To show that two spaces are NOT isomorphic, you need to show there cannot exist ANY bijective linear maps between the two spaces. So, by showing that this particular map is not an isomorphism doesn't show that the spaces are not isomorphic. It only shows that "this" map is not an isomorphism.

Comment: @AnuragA Ahh, dang! Once again I've fallen into the Three Mosqueteers trap (one for all), thinking a single example defines the whole...

Comment: To show that $\mathbb{R}^4 \not\cong \mathbb{R}^3$, consider that any linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^4 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ can be represented via a $3 \times 4$ matrix $A$ as $T(x)=Ax$. Now consider the kernel and argue that it has a non-zero vector in it, so cannot be one-one.

Comment: @AnuragA Ohh! Enlightening!!

Comment: @AnuragA Just a silly last question: if I reversed the question, for example having two sets $A$ and $B$ (generic), and I want to know if $A \cong B$, is it sufficient for me to find just one linear $1:1$ onto map? Or should I have to prove it generally anyway?

Comment: First of all if you have two sets, then you have to describe what exactly do you mean by an "isomorphism". In the sense, are the sets vector spaces, groups, rings, graphs etc., i.e. what is the underlying algebraic structure of the sets that is being compared? Having answered that, to show two algebraic structures are isomorphic, we only need to come up with one such function that serves as an isomorphism.

Comment: @AnuragA I recognized the incompleteness of my question in the exact moment I send it (indeed what does "set" mean?). It's nice to understand something from time to time haha. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind your developments is correct, but your proof needs to be systematized to general cases. The easiest formulation turns out to be a proof by contradiction.

Let $U,V$ be $n$- and $m$-dimensional vector spaces respectively, whose bases are denoted by $\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\} \subset U$ and $\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\} \subset V$. Without loss of generality, we can suppose that $n > m$. Now, let's assume that $U \cong V$. In consequence, there exists an isomorphism $\phi : U \rightarrow V$. Without loss of generality again, we can choose $\phi(u_1) = v_1$, $\phi(u_2) = v_2$, etc., until $\phi(u_m) = v_m$. Then, $\phi(u_{m+1}) := \lambda_1v_1 + \ldots + \lambda_mv_m$. Yet, one has $\phi(\lambda_1v_1 + \ldots + \lambda_mv_m) = \lambda_1v_1 + \ldots + \lambda_mv_m$ by linearity, meaning that $\phi$ is not injective and *a fortiori* not isomorphic, hence finally $U \not\cong V$ by contradiction.